# single function for emotions,links,preserving line breaks and wordwrap

Tags: php

Hello all i am working on a project where i need to have find any url/links/emails, preserve the line brakes,replace the special symbol with emotions and also wordwrap. so i was wondering that if all these things are possible with only a single function or not currently i am using this function for emotions

```
function emotions($text) {
$icons = array(
        ':)'    =>  '<img src="smiles/smilee.png" class="icon_smile" title="smiling :)"/>',
        ':d'    =>  '<img src="smiles/lol.gif" class="icon_smile" title="Laughing :d"/>',
        ';)'    =>  '<img src="smiles/wink.png" class="icon_smile" title="Wink ;)"/>',
        ':p'    =>  '<img src="smiles/tongue.png" class="icon_smile" title="Tounge :p"/>',
        ':('    =>  '<img src="smiles/sad.png"  class="icon_smile" title="Sad face :("/>',
        ':o'    =>  '<img src="smiles/shock.png" class="icon_smile" title="Shocking :o"/>',
        ':|'    =>  '<img src="smiles/straight.png" class="icon_smile" title="straight :|"/>',
        '<3'   =>  '<img src="smiles/heart.png" class="heart" title="Heart <3"/>',
        '::s'   =>  '<img src="smiles/sexy.png" class="icon_smile" title="Sexy <s"/>',
        ':D'   =>  '<img src="smiles/lols.gif" class="icon_smile" title="lol :D"/>',

        ':(('   =>  '<img src="smiles/cry.gif" class="icon_smile" title="crying :(("/>',
        ':X'   =>  '<img src="smiles/silent.gif" class="icon_smile" title="sealed lips :X"/>',
        ':B'   =>  '<img src="smiles/bla.gif" style="width:29px;vertical-align:middle;" title="bla bla :B"/>',
        ':C'   =>  '<img src="smiles/coll.gif" style="width:24px;vertical-align:middle;" title="coll me :C"/>'
);
return strtr($text, $icons);
}

?>
```

and i know that for wordwrap i can use the function wordwrap and for line brakes nl2br but i want all these in a single function please help me with this

Comment: and one more thing how can i use this function to find links and emails

Answer (score 1):

You could use [str_replace()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [array_keys()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
function emotions($text) {
    $icons = array(
        ':)'    =>  '<img src="smiles/smilee.png" class="icon_smile" title="smiling :)"/>',
        ':d'    =>  '<img src="smiles/lol.gif" class="icon_smile" title="Laughing :d"/>',
        ';)'    =>  '<img src="smiles/wink.png" class="icon_smile" title="Wink ;)"/>',
        ':p'    =>  '<img src="smiles/tongue.png" class="icon_smile" title="Tounge :p"/>',
        ':('    =>  '<img src="smiles/sad.png"  class="icon_smile" title="Sad face :("/>',
        ':o'    =>  '<img src="smiles/shock.png" class="icon_smile" title="Shocking :o"/>',
        ':|'    =>  '<img src="smiles/straight.png" class="icon_smile" title="straight :|"/>',
        '<3'   =>  '<img src="smiles/heart.png" class="heart" title="Heart <3"/>',
        '::s'   =>  '<img src="smiles/sexy.png" class="icon_smile" title="Sexy <s"/>',
        ':D'   =>  '<img src="smiles/lols.gif" class="icon_smile" title="lol :D"/>',
        ':(('   =>  '<img src="smiles/cry.gif" class="icon_smile" title="crying :(("/>',
        ':X'   =>  '<img src="smiles/silent.gif" class="icon_smile" title="sealed lips :X"/>',
        ':B'   =>  '<img src="smiles/bla.gif" style="width:29px;vertical-align:middle;" title="bla bla :B"/>',
        ':C'   =>  '<img src="smiles/coll.gif" style="width:24px;vertical-align:middle;" title="coll me :C"/>'
    );
    return str_replace(array_keys($icons), array_values($icons), $text);
}
```

You should use nl2br and additional functions to the result of the function. But of course you can use these functions in this function, too.

Comment: i think probably u did not understand what i meant was currently i am using diffrent functions for all these things replacing emotions,finding links and preserving line breaks but i want a function which can does all these by itself. one for all

Comment: You can just call them altogether. `return nl2br(wordwrap(str_replace(array_keys($icons), array_values($icons), $text)));`

Answer (score 1):

You can just go and call the 3 functions altogether:

`wordwrap(nl2br(emotions($text))[, $width, $break])`

You can also use *wordwrap* and *nl2br* in the return statement of you function...

**Creating custom function**

```
function letsDoMagic($text, $width = 75, $break = "\n") {
  return wordwrap(nl2br(emotions($text)), $width, $break);
}

// And then somewere in your code
letsDoMagic($text);
```

Here you have, 1 function call. As I said in comments PHP does not have a native function to do all this work in one call, and this is the reason you can create your own functions :-)

Comment: ya currently i am doing like this only but i want a single function for all of these

Comment: You could just throw wordwrap and nl2br in your emoticions() function. I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: You can create a function wich wraps all those calls, but natively PHP does not have a function that does this 3 things in one call so I cannot see your point....